# How can I validate a new users Name (not username)

Tags: development, user, registration

By default, Joomla will insure that a username and email is not already in use.  I need to extend that to insure that the user provides a first name and last name (and is unique).

What is the best way to do this...I've explored using onUserBeforeSave in a user plugin, but this strikes me to be too late in the process.

Comment: Are you sure you want to have unique names? This should be a very specific case, otherwise I can't think why first/last name must be unique and how this could be useful.

Comment: It is a very specific case....its a small collection of Television producers, and uniqueness is part of the game...even without that, the first AND last requirement remains.  Failing a user plugin test "works", but need to figure out how to set the error text that follows: "Save failed with the following error".

Comment: Also you may edit your `#__users` table structure in phpMyAdmin and change the "Index Type" of `idx_name` to `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Have to avoid hacks, and this rule only applies to a particular usergroup anyways, but thx

Comment: Yes, it's a DB hack but I think it applies to all users.

Comment: On the contrary, FORCING everyone to use a unique NAME (not username), would be very bad....many, many people share the same name.

Comment: Well, your registration form has a field for "first name" and another field for "last name" and you store them in a separate table or concatenate them in `name` column of `#__users` table. Also, you have to avoid hacks, so I agree with you: the best way is to create a plugin as you mentioned to check the uniqueness of fields and display errors if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this solution doesn't sit well with me, but it does work using the user plugin:

```
public function onUserBeforeSave($oldUser, $isnew, $newUser) {
    if($test == 'fails') {
        $error = ' First and Last Name must be specified';
        throw new Exception($error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note - if you throw an Exception `return` will never be reached.

Comment: A true...remnant development code - thx